# Adobe Indesign JavaScript: using app.findGrep() and app.changeGrep() consecutively

Tags: javascript, regex, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I have a script that should find and replace predefined terms and mark the changes visually on a separate layer.

The process basically works in two steps:

1. Loop through a list of expressions, look for every expression with **app.findGrep()** and insert Note-Markers at the beginning and at the end of a match.
2. Loop through the same list again and find & *replace* with corresponding terms of another predefined list, using **app.changeGrep()**. After that, use the positions of the markers to draw rectangles on a new layer in order to visualize the changes.

The problem is that even though Step 1 works fine (marks show up at their correct positions), step 2 doesn't seem to do anything, *unless* I change the findWhat parameter to an expression that hasn't been used already in the list of step 1.

So, my guess is that Indesign somehow caches all performed searches and prevents any further look-ups with those expressions.

However, if I use the standard find&replace form after the execution of the script, I can still find any expression from the list without any issues.

Can anyone see how I can solve this issue?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It seems doubtful that indesign would cache searches. Is there a reason you can't do everything in one step and see if that works?

Comment: I tried using just changeGrep(), but then I only know how the get the positions in the text BEFORE the replacements happen (var t = app.changeGrep()). So, the rectangles I draw only fit the first change... does that make sense to you? :-)

Comment: So, I found out that the notes-marks were the culprits!

When inserted *within* the match found by **findGrep()** (in order to just enclose the relevant characters to be changed and not the whole Regex), the expression wouldn't match with changeGrep() anymore. Strangely though, I could still find the expression using the normal find&replace mask in InDesign, despite the marks...
I solved the issue partially by placing the marks outside the match, so that the expression searched for stays unchanged by findGrep() and that no marks would confuse changeGrep().